# Defining a Variable

Tags: variables, slider, netlogo

I am very very new to coding. I'm trying to write up a code for a game called "Heroes and Cowards" (though it goes by many other names). The book gives me this code for the setup procedure, but netlogo keeps asking me to define number, and I don't know where to do that. I need to be able to make the variable number into a slider on the interface.

The book says to write this as code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4rWB.png)

Can anyone help me out? I understand it maybe obvious. I've just hit a newbie road block.
Thanks!

Comment: This model is in the NetLogo Models Library.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, it's better for questions if you include your code examples as a code block rather than an image. To do so, paste your code in, select it, and click the "Code Sample" button.

To answer your question- to create a slider, click the Interface tab in Netlogo. Then, click the drop-down menu right beside the "Add" button (green plus sign). It will give you some options- select "Slider." Next, click the "Add" button  will change your cursor to a cross. Click somewhere in white area of the interface space and a new window will pop up. In the "Global variable" field, put "number" (not in quotes). Set the values if you want, or just click OK. If that all works, you will have created a variable called "number" that is set to the current value of the slider.